# Multi level pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I need to maintain position of "each scrip per team per account". So I think pandas `groupby` might be used. I have tried to state my problem in comment of dataframe aswell. The position column has been added manually by me.

Initial df I have

```
             time account scrip  buy_price  sell_price  qty   team  
0  06/07/17 09:36      A1  FUT1       50.0         NaN    2  team1         
1  06/07/17 09:46      A2  FUT1      100.0         NaN    2  team1         
2  06/07/17 09:56      A3  FUT1       10.0         NaN    2  team2         
3  06/07/17 09:57      A3  FUT1        NaN        10.0    2  team2         
4  06/07/17 09:58      A1  FUT1        NaN        50.0    1  team1         
5  06/07/17 09:59      A3  FUT1        NaN        50.0    1  team2
```

I need to add position. The position column has been added manually by me and in the comment I write additional remark for clarity on how position is calculated.

```
             time account scrip  buy_price  sell_price  qty   team  position                                    comment
0  06/07/17 09:36      A1  FUT1       50.0         NaN    2  team1         2  this can only be sold by team1 account A1
1  06/07/17 09:46      A2  FUT1      100.0         NaN    2  team1         2  this can only be sold by team1 account A2
2  06/07/17 09:56      A3  FUT1       10.0         NaN    2  team2         2  this can only be sold by team2 account A3
3  06/07/17 09:57      A3  FUT1        NaN        10.0    2  team2         0                 sold by team 2 in  acc A3 
4  06/07/17 09:58      A1  FUT1        NaN        50.0    1  team1         1                  sold by team 1 in acc A1 
5  06/07/17 09:59      A3  FUT1        NaN        50.0    1  team2        -1                   sold by team 2 in acc A3
```

The above example is for just 1 scrip FUT1, there would be many scrips. My end result would be something similar to.

```
Team Account Scrip Position
team1 A1      FUT1 1 
      A2      FUT1 2
team2 A3      FUT1 -1
```

End result can be worked on later, once position is calculated successfully. 
My approach: making a unique key in each row so as to know when to + or - position. eg. `A1_FUT1_team1` for `row1` `A2_FUT1_team1` for `row2`. Then add subtract matching keys. Is this anyway a good approach?

Comment: Can you show what you actually tried?

Comment: how ? row1:pos=+2 because 2 qty bought by t1a1, row2:pos=+2 because 2 qty bought by t1a2, row3:pos:+2 because 2 qty bought by t2a3, row4:pos=0 because 2 qty sold by t23 and so on. What wrong do you see.?
t1a1=>team1account1

Comment: oh now i see it, the comments column isn't clear enough though

Answer (score 3):

Your problem can be solved easily in two steps:

**First Step:**

```
import math
df['some_stuff'] = df.apply(lambda x: -x.qty if math.isnan(x.buy_price) else x.qty,axis=1)
```

this line is creating a new column `some_stuff`, why I did this is just to introduce some logic of `gain and loss` in your data.

if you don't want a new column and you like the idea just replace `qty` column with it like this:

```
df['qty'] = df.apply(lambda x: -x.qty if math.isnan(x.buy_price) else x.qty,axis=1)
```

next, I use this new column to create your `position column` as follows:

```
df['position'] = df.groupby(['team','account','scrip'])['some_stuff'].cumsum()
```

which generates this column:

```
position
       2
       2
       2
       0
       1
      -1
```

*bonus:*

if you want to delete the extra column `some_stuff` just use:

```
del df['some_stuff']
```

**Second Step:**

This is the step where you get your final grouped table with this line:

```
print(df.groupby(['team', 'account', 'scrip']).min())
```

final output:

```
                               time  buy_price  sell_price  qty  position
team  account scrip                                                      
team1 A1      FUT1   06/07/17 09:36       50.0        50.0    1         1
      A2      FUT1   06/07/17 09:46      100.0         NaN    2         2
team2 A3      FUT1   06/07/17 09:56       10.0        10.0    1        -1
```

I believe this answers your questions.

**Documentation:**

[pandas.DataFrame.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

[pandas.Groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html)

[pandas.DataFrame.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html)

[pandas.DataFrame.min](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.min.html)

Comment: thanks for the help, I'm trying to embedd this part to my code. I think `df['position'] = df.groupby(['team','account'])['some_stuff'].cumsum()` should be `df['position'] = df.groupby(['team','account','scrip'])['some_stuff'].cumsum()` because I need positions per scrip

Comment: @pythonRcpp well about that, i don't know how the rest of your data is, and since in your comment column there was no reference to scrip i just did something suitable for the sample provided, but yeah, for the entire thing, i think you should group by team, account and scrip. i'll add it in the answer as well

Comment: heyy, is there a way to get the last line of each group? After doing `df['position'] = df.groupby(['team','account','scrip'])['some_stuff'].cumsum()
` I want to have another dataframe which only has last line of each group created. (so I have final position for each group).

Comment: @pythonRcpp, even if i kind of have an idea of what you're trying to achieve, I can't be sure or give you and answer that could be wrong before testing it, so create another detailed question, with some sample and the desired output, and pass the link here i'll check it out. sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're looking for?

```
df.groupby(['team', 'account', 'scrip']).min()
```

it gives me:

```
                      time  buy_price  sell_price  qty  position
team  account scrip                                             
team1 A1      FUT1   09:36       50.0        50.0    1         1
      A2      FUT1   09:46      100.0         NaN    2         2
team2 A3      FUT1   09:56       10.0        10.0    1        -1
```

that's a few more columns than you wanted but you can subset out what you're looking for.

(groupby by default moves the grouped columns to a multilevel index, but if this isn't what you want you can add `as_index=False` as an arg in the `.groupby()`)

Comment: I first need to add position column. Once it is added correctly, your solution is fine. But main problem is how to get the position column.

Comment: oh! I'm not sure I understand how you're calculating position. is position a rank? A sales point?

Comment: no position is like if you buy n qty you go +n in position (for that team for that account for that scrip) if you sell n qty , you go -n in position. buy 2, then sell 1, makes your position 1. reading the comment in 2nd df may help