# Pandas multi-level groupby date, year, preserve hour

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame with hourly values for a few years and want to get the five maximum daily values for each year while preserving the hour at which each highest value happened. Here's the data:

```
mw
datetime_beginning_ept            
2018-01-01 00:00:00     112288.391
2018-01-01 01:00:00     111308.584
2018-01-01 02:00:00     110402.115
2018-01-01 03:00:00     110466.337
2018-01-01 04:00:00     111476.085
...                            ...
2020-12-31 19:00:00      94429.608
2020-12-31 20:00:00      91971.422
2020-12-31 21:00:00      89470.602
2020-12-31 22:00:00      86863.353
2020-12-31 23:00:00      84287.155
```

The desired output would be something like:

```
mw
datetime_beginning_ept            
2018-07-01 17:00:00     142288.391
2018-07-20 14:00:00     151308.584
2018-08-01 16:00:00     140402.115
2018-07-28 17:00:00     140466.337
2018-07-10 18:00:00     141476.085
2019-07-18 17:00:00     145466.337
2019-07-05 18:00:00     146476.085
...                            ...
2020-07-31 17:00:00     184287.155
```

I have tried following the instructions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45052636/multi-level-pandas-groupby) as well as using multilevel `groupby` with two new columns for year and month-day-year with `max()` and `nlargest(5)` but none of them worked as I need. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do in two steps

1. get the maximal daily
2. get x maximal each year

Something like this:

```
(series.loc[series.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='D')).idxmax()] # daily max
       .groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='Y')).nlargest(5)
)
```

Comment: I got `ValueError: Cannot index with multidimensional key`. Any other ideas?

Comment: @BernardoTrindade is your data multiIndex? If not, the code alone should not yield the error.  Did you do anything with the output?

Comment: It isn't, it has one datetime index and columns `mw  year     Y          D`. No output is being generated because of the error.

Comment: Oh I see. It’s my fault. Needs freq in groupby. Updated. See if it helps.

Comment: @BernardoTrindade I don't know what's wrong. See the code [here](https://ideone.com/hS65jn). There's no error.

Comment: It worked now. It was my fault. I was adding a column 'Y' and another 'D' to the data making it a DataFrame--quite ashamed of admitting that. Thanks a lot!